# Where is my .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I have been using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), and I would really like to save my settings. The problem I am having is that I cannot find my .vimrc file, and it is not in the standard `/home/user/.vimrc` location. How might I find this file?

Comment: If it isn't there, create it.

Comment: My Ubuntu machine had it in a file named `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to locate the vimrc file used by vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977649/how-to-locate-the-vimrc-file-used-by-vim-editor)

Comment: Confirming Lubuntu 21.10 follows the convention in the @ckjbgames comment (```/usr/share/vim/vimrc``` without the period). However, this file contains the following comment: ```Vim will load $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim if the user does not have a vimrc. This happens after /etc/vim/vimrc(.local) are loaded, so it will override any settings in these files.```

Comment: My ArchLinux (firmware version: linux-6.1.3.arch1-1) has vimrc at location: /etc/vimrc, you can use ':scriptnames' command in any vim session to display the files that vim has loaded which obviously displays "vimrc"\'s location usually at the very top.

Answer (score 672, accepted):

You need to create it. In most installations I've used it hasn't been created by default.

You usually create it as `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: also check /etc/vim/vimrc

Comment: @Nateshbhat: should I keep using `/etc/vim/vimrc` or copy that to `~/.vimrc`? Or can I have both?

Comment: If you want to customize it, I'd copy it local first. Otherwise you are changing settings for all users.

Comment: You should be aware that if you create this file, it will ignore all settings in the system vimrc file. (For example `/etc/vim/vimrc`.) This confused me no end after I created a `.vimrc`, didn't populate it completely with all my usual options (because it was on a server that I didn't intend to do much work on) and it left my vim in a broken or nonfunctional state.

Comment: Hey!. I am using VIM extension in VSCode . Is there any way to change the keybindings of the extension?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson That's a good question! You should post it as a separate question to post and ask, separately, as the answer is specific to VSCode.

Comment: @AlG , Okay just I found it out and it was pretty simple. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030352/12982627

Comment: This answer was only helpful to the OP in his context but not to anybody else who came here trying to find out "Where is my .vimrc file".

Comment: Why is this not by default? It's far superior than not having it

Comment: @Nateshbhat hope this vimrc is equals to .vimrc

Comment: @linjiejun Most that I've seen have your local copy as `.vimrc` and the default one as `vimrc`. That said, it can vary by installation. See Laurence's answer below.

Answer (score 411):

These methods work, if you already have a .vimrc file:

`:scriptnames` list all the .vim files that Vim loaded for you, including your `.vimrc` file.

`:e $MYVIMRC` open & edit the current .vimrc that you are using, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to view the path in status bar.

Comment: @MorganWilde Not necessarily, `:scriptnames` and `:e $MYVIMRC` both return blank outputs for me.

Comment: +1 for `:scriptnames`. However `$MYVIMRC` isn't guaranteed to be set, for example when starting vim with `vim -u filename`.

Comment: :scriptnames has vimrc but not .vimrc, are they the same? I find them located in my usr/share folder, would adding ~/.vimrc (as accepted answer) even do anything then without further configuration? Is that a way to add user specific options to the vimrc perhaps?

Comment: Note that `:e $MYVIMRC` only works when there is a `vimrc` file in the first place. Otherwise this will start edting a file literally called `$MYVIMRC`.

Comment: Awesome answer. Mine was sitting in `/etc/vimrc`

Comment: @Shadoninja - that wasn't "yours", that is the global `rc` file. Whatever you define in your `.vimrc` file (in most cases in your home directory) will override the defaults in `/etc/vimrc`.

Answer (score 123):

## Short answer:

To create your vimrc, start up Vim and do one of the following:

```
:e $HOME/.vimrc  " on Unix, Mac or OS/2

:e $HOME/_vimrc  " on Windows

:e s:.vimrc      " on Amiga
```

Insert the settings you want, and save the file.

Note that exisitence of this file will disable the `compatible` option. See below for details.

## Long answer:

There are two kinds of vimrc:

- the *user vimrc* in `$HOME`
- the *system vimrc* in `$VIM` (on Amiga systems, `s:.vimrc` is considered a user vimrc)

**The user vimrc file often does not exist until created by the user.** If you cannot find `$HOME/.vimrc` (or `$HOME/_vimrc` on Windows) then you can, and probably should, just create it.

**The system vimrc should normally be left unmodified** and is located in the `$VIM`<sup>*</sup> directory. The system vimrc is *not* a good place you keep your personal settings. If you modify this file your changes may be overwritten if you ever upgrade Vim. Also, changes here will affect other users on a multi-user system. In most cases, settings in the user vimrc will override settings in the system vimrc.

From `:help vimrc`:

> A file that contains initialization commands is called a "vimrc" file.
>   Each line in a vimrc file is executed as an Ex command line.  It is
>   sometimes also referred to as "exrc" file.  They are the same type of
>   file, but "exrc" is what Vi always used, "vimrc" is a Vim specific
>   name.  Also see |vimrc-intro|.
>
> Places for your personal initializations:
>
> ```
>     Unix            $HOME/.vimrc or $HOME/.vim/vimrc
>     OS/2            $HOME/.vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc
>                     or $VIM/.vimrc (or _vimrc)
>     MS-Windows      $HOME/_vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc
>                     or $VIM/_vimrc
>     Amiga           s:.vimrc, home:.vimrc, home:vimfiles:vimrc
>                     or $VIM/.vimrc
> ```
>
> The files are searched in the order specified above and only the first
>   one that is found is read.

(MacOS counts as Unix for the above.)

Note that the mere *existence* of a user vimrc will change Vim's behavior by turning off the `compatible` option. From `:help compatible-default`:

> When Vim starts, the 'compatible' option is on.  This will be used when Vim
>   starts its initializations.  But as soon as a user vimrc file is found, or a
>   vimrc file in the current directory, or the "VIMINIT" environment variable is
>   set, it will be set to 'nocompatible'.  This has the side effect of setting or
>   resetting other options (see 'compatible').  But only the options that have
>   not been set or reset will be changed.

---

<sup>* `$VIM` may not be set in your shell, but is always set inside Vim. If you want to see what it's set to, start up Vim and use the command `:echo $VIM`</sup>

Answer (score 31):

As additional information, mostly in macOS, the .vimrc file is located at directory:

```
/usr/share/vim/.vimrc
```

Comment: That is the system vimrc. It's better to edit $HOME/.vimrc, and to create it if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: If .vimrc file is not created in home directory then vi references `/usr/share/vim/.vimrc` file for use.

Comment: Same in Ubuntu, as I found.

Answer (score 28):

```
:echo($MYVIMRC)
```

will give you the location of your .vimrc file.

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

will open it.

Comment: I take back the following: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '$MYVIMRC'

Comment: @YannisDran - Uhmm, what?

Comment: @Idigas I was typing :echo(xxx) on my command window but I realized now you meant to type this into the vim editor. However, even though :e xxx works, the :echo(xxx) doesn't. It says E121 Undefined Variable: xxx    E15: Invalid Expression : ($xxx)

Comment: @YannisDran - Just to be clear, you got that error upon typing :echo($myvimrc) into the vim command line? Not :echo(myvimrc) by any chance?

Comment: I use the $ and I did it into the vi editor(Typing : enables command line). Btw, now vim responds nothing, it only puts the indicator at the first line of vim. (Vim-Vi Improved v.7.3 on OSX)

Comment: @Idigas Great. Could you tell me the equivalent $MYVIMRC to .bashrc file if any?

Comment: @leoadams - I don't know of any (I'm on Windows). I believe this is only a Vim thing. But if I find out anything I'll post it here.

Comment: @Idigas Yeah, I agree with you. It's only a Vim thing.

Answer (score 24):

on unix `vim --version` tells you the various locations of the vim config files :

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

Comment: Can verify that this works with the VIM that bundles with Git for Windows.  (Noting this only because so much that an SO answer might presume that DOESN'T work in Git Bash.)

Comment: I prefer this answer, since **it will always provide updated and authentic information** regarding the valid vimrc file paths for a given system and vim installation.

Answer (score 22):

For whatever reason, these answers didn't quite work for me. This is what worked for me instead:

In Vim, the `:version` command gives you the paths of system and user vimrc and gvimrc files (among other things), and the output looks something like this:

```
 system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
   user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
    user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
  user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
```

The one you want is `user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"`

So to edit the file: `vim $HOME/.vimrc`

Source: *[Open vimrc file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimrc)*

Comment: I don't understand how the existing answers didn't quite work for you when in fact the solution you proposed is already covered by them. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005877/1743811) mentions `$HOME/.vimrc` and [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921485/1743811) mentions `~/.vimrc` which is the same as `$HOME/.vimrc`.

Comment: Completely agree with you. What I meant to say was lost when my answer was edited

Answer (score 16):

Open Vim, and in normal mode type:

```
:echo $VIM
```

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: For me it outputs only `/usr/share/vim`. Version 8.2.100, Arch Linux.

Comment: This tells you the directory your system vimrc is located in, but it doesn't tell you where your user vimrc should go, or what its name should be.

Comment: Well, the question "where" is the vimrc file. 
Where user vimrc should go? Put it into `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`, notice that latter don't have dot in front of it.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen this must be the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

## Useful Information can be obtained using the `find` command

---

```
find / -iname "*vimrc*" -type f 2>/dev/null
```

---

There are many answers already, but it can sometimes be useful to simply run a "find" for anything containing the name "vimrc".

The reason is that this will show you what files you actualy have available on the system currently, rather than what you **might** put on your system. (The information for which you would obtain from `:version` as explained in other answers.)

## Example result on my system

On my system this produces

```
/usr/share/vim/vim82/vimrc_example.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim82/gvimrc_example.vim
/etc/vim/gvimrc
/etc/vim/vimrc
/etc/vim/vimrc.tiny
```

Which is quite useful because it tells us that there are 2 example files installed in the share directorys for both gvim and vim, and that there are also some system-wide config files below `/etc/`.

On my system, I also have a file at `~/.vimrc` but this does not appear in this list because it is a link to another file, stored under `~/Linux-Config`. But you won't have this directory, it's specific to machines I use on my own network.

## Detailed Explanation of `find` syntax used

Explanation:

- find starting at the root directory `/` (find works recursively)
- anything containing the **case insensitive** regex `*vimrc*` which means any name with `vimrc` (case insensitive) in it somewhere, can be preceeded or followed by anything or nothing (`*`)
- type = files (not directory/symlink etc)
- throw all errors to `/dev/null` otherwise the output is spammed with unreadable errors from `/proc`

Comment: if the `*` acts like a regular glob, you should do instead: `find / \( -iname "*vimrc*" -o -iname ".*vimrc*" \) -type f 2>/dev/null` , otherwise you'll miss the filenames starting with a `.` (such as `~/.vimrc` , etc) as in a regular shell glob, `*filename` doesn't grab files starting with a `.` (as those are "lightly hidden" this naming scheme in most unix/linux commands (compare `ls -l` and `ls -al`, and `echo *` will show only those who don't start with a `.`) , and thus a regular `*` glob is not including those by default)

Answer (score 8):

Where is the `.vimrc` file?  It depends on the OS.  As you can see, you were looking for `/home/$user/.vimrc`, which probably means you are using BSD / Linux.  Here are the locations for each OS...

- ***BSD / Linux*** : `/home/$user/.vimrc`
- ***SunOS / Solaris*** : `/export/home/$user/.vimrc`
- ***MacOS*** : `/Users/$user/.vimrc`
- ***Android*** : `/data/media/$userid/.vimrc`
- ***Unix*** : `$root/home/$user/.vimrc`
- ***AT&T Unix*** : `$root/usr/$user/.vimrc`
- ***Unix-Derived*** :

  - `/var/users/$user/.vimrc`
  - `/u01/$user/.vimrc`
  - `/usr/$user/.vimrc`
  - `/user/$user/.vimrc`
  - `/users/$user/.vimrc` (Source: [Wikipedia: Default home directory per operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_home_directory_per_operating_system).)

If it doesn't exist, create it with `~/.vimrc`.

In addition, the `root` user has their own special `.vimrc` file, which can be found in `/root/.vimrc` on BSD / Linux (and in equivalent locations for the other OS's).

The location is set in the `$HOME` variable, which is always set in Linux environments. ([Source: StackExchange->Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123858/466373).)

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few more tips:

- In [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) the global one is at `/etc/vimrc`. There are some comments in there with helpful details.
- Since the filename starts with a `.`, it's hidden unless you use `ls -a` to show ALL files.
- Typing `:version` while in Vim will show you a bunch of interesting information including the file location.
- If you're not sure what `~/.vimrc` means [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384582/linux-ubuntu-directory-location-vim-syntax).

Answer (score 7):

actually you have one vimrc in

> /etc/vimrc

when you edit something in there the changes will effect all users 
if you don't want that you can create a local vimrc in

> ~/.vimrc

the changes here will only effect the one user

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to share how I set showing the line number as the default on Mac.

1. In a terminal, type `cd`. This will help you go to the home folder.
2. In the terminal, type `vi .vimrc`. This will create an empty vimrc system file which you want to use.
3. In the file, type `set number`, and then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the keyboard and type in `:wq`. This will set the line number shown in the default setting file `vimrc` and save it.
4. `vi something` to see if this works. If not, try to restart the terminal completely.

If in a terminal, type in `cd /usr/share/vim/`, go to that folder, and type in `ls`. You can directly see a file named vimrc. But it's a system file that says read only. I feel it's not a good idea to try modify it. So following the above steps to create a vimrc by yourself is better. It worked for me.

Comment: One thing I needed to change to the above for my CentOS7 install : after step 1, type "cd username".

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything in the previous answer and couldn't find a `.vimrc` file, so I had to make one.

I copied the example file, `cp vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc`.

I had to create the file, copying from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/vimrc_example.vim` to `~/.vimrc`. Those were the instructions in the `vimrc_example` file.

My solution is for Unix for other operating systems. According to the Vim documentation, your destination path should be as follows:

```
    For Unix and OS/2   : ~/.vimrc
    For Amiga           : s:.vimrc
    For MS-DOS and Win32: $VIM\_vimrc
    For OpenVMS         : sys$login:.vimrc
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about in other versions of Vim, but in Vim 9.0, the output of `vim --version` includes great information about this. On my system, the output includes the following:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

Answer (score 2):

In [SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_Server) and [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) the global one is located at `/etc/vimrc`.

To edit it, simply do `vi /etc/vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

The **vimrc** file in *Ubuntu ([12.04 (Precise Pangolin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29))*: I tried `:scriptnames` in Vim, and it shows both `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc`.

But I had manually created `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

From cmd (Windows):

```
C\Users\You> `vim foo.txt`
```

Now in Vim, enter command mode by typing: "**:**" (i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>)

```
:tabedit $HOME/.vimrc
```

Comment: This presumes a keyboard with a US layout.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are so many answers and none of them helped me.

Until I ran

```
:checkhealth
```

in vim and found out that in my case, the vim config file should be named `init.vim` (under `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`).

Comment: This would be because you're using Neovim, which defaults to using the (preferred) $XDG_CONFIG_HOME directory for app configuration. This helps to de-clutter the $HOME directory. There's been an RFC out on Vim for a few years now to move to the same convention, though not much has come of it:

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2034

Answer (score 0):

the name of the file in my system, installed with Garuda Linux is file:///etc/xdg/nvim/sysinit.vim, so try to find this file and add your custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to edit my .vimrc file and this worked for me (macOS Ventura 13.0.1 December 2022).

```
touch ~/.vimrc
vim ~/.vimrc
```

I was then able to edit the file to my heart's content, and the next time I ran *vim* it picked up my changes.

Answer (score -2):

if in Windows, it could be in your C directory under Program Files(x86) in the folder "vim"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).