# first character of command does not show in vim

Tags: vim

I am learning vim through vimtutor, in the lesson2.1, it said:

```
  NOTE: The letter  d  will appear on the last line of the screen as you type
    it.  Vim is waiting for you to type  w .  If you see another character
    than  d  you typed something wrong; press  <ESC>  and start over.
```

However, after I type "d", there is nothing showed at the bottom of my screen. Here is a screen shot of my vim after I type "d". I did not change anything after I install vim. I also tried in the vim app instead of terminal. I still canont see anything after I typed "d". Do I have any misunderstanding here?My system is OS X 10.9.5,vim is 7.4.258.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vimtutor type:

```
:set showcmd
```

By default vimtutor runs as plain vim, without any extra settings. To have this behaviour in vim by default, you can add

```
set showcmd
```

line to your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: In case if you did not find a .vimrc you have to create it and add 'set showcmd'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file