# How do I create the folder .vimrc?

Tags: macos, file, vim, macvim

I'm new to VIM so I was doing the VIM tutorial and in the Lesson 7.2 it asks to edit the .vimrc file in the ~/.vimrc directory by typing this command: `:e ~/.vimrc` but I get an error `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` I didn't know what to do so I tried to find if that file existed but it didn't. I searched for "Where is my .vimrc file" and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921485/5220885 but I don't know how to create it, I wanted to ask in the comments but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with `.vimrc` as such, rather it is simply Vim warning you that you are trying to edit a different file when you are already editing another one with unsaved changes.

If you write the changes to your current file, `:w`, first you won't get the error. Alternatively as the error suggests you can discard the changes and switch to editing `.vimrc` by adding the exclamation mark to the command, `:e! ~/.vimrc`

Of course you can just type `vim ~/.vimrc` in the Terminal to open and edit the file.

HTH