# Where is the default vimrc located on Mac

Tags: macos, vim

Where can I find the default vimrc on Mac when there is no `~/.vimrc`.
On some Linux its located in the `/etc/vimrc`

Comment: You need to create it by yourself. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file

Comment: @CodePlayer the problem is without the the file I syntax highlighting and mouse select and other things are turned on. But when I create the ~/.vimrc file, it removes all the default config and uses the file config. ( I want to copy the default to the vimrc and modify as appropriate.

Comment: `echo $MYVIMRC` or `:version`

Answer (score 45):

Type in Terminal: `vim --version`
as you want check the vim's version, then scroll down you will find something like; `user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 32):

The path used by macOS's default vim install is `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`.

On my system at the moment (macOS 10.12.5), these are its contents:

```
" Configuration file for vim
set modelines=0     " CVE-2007-2438

" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=2     " more powerful backspacing

" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "crontab -e"
au BufWrite /private/tmp/crontab.* set nowritebackup nobackup
" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "chpass"
au BufWrite /private/etc/pw.* set nowritebackup nobackup
```

Comment: If you aren't using the default, here's the easiest way to discover where it is: `:scriptnames`. The first line should be the system `vimrc`.

Comment: can't edit in the /usr/share/vim/vimrc , however, you can create one in your home path: vim ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 10):

You can use `:echo $MYVIMRC` to print it. Also, you can have a look at `:version` which gives list of places being searched.

Comment: I tried all the paths that vim version gives but it shows nothing. Does vim automatically load a config within the binary if nothing is found? @dlmeetei

Comment: Are you using default vim or macvim

Comment: @dlmeetrei I am using the default one installed

Comment: @isethi, Not sure if default is broken on Mac, People seems to prefer `macvim` on Mac

Answer (score 6):

If you're just looking to change VIM defaults for your profile, macOS looks for `~/.vimrc`, so if you make the file you can change your vim settings there.

Answer (score 1):

For my homebrew generated vim the location of the default vimrc file is:

`/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim`

Here, the numbers 81 correspond to the vim version number.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/lib/vim/doc/*.txt
The Vim documentation files.  Use ":help doc-file-list" to get the complete list.

```
   /usr/local/lib/vim/doc/tags
                  The tags file used for finding information in the documentation files.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
                  System wide syntax initializations.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/syntax/*.vim
                  Syntax files for various languages.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/vimrc
                  System wide Vim initializations.

   ~/.vimrc       Your personal Vim initializations.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/gvimrc
                  System wide gvim initializations.

   ~/.gvimrc      Your personal gvim initializations.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/optwin.vim
                  Script used for the ":options" command, a nice way to view and set options.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/menu.vim
                  System wide menu initializations for gvim.

   /usr/local/lib/vim/bugreport.vim
                  Script to generate a bug report.  See ":help bugs".

   /usr/local/lib/vim/filetype.vim
                  Script to detect the type of a file by its name.  See ":help 'filetype'".

   /usr/local/lib/vim/scripts.vim
                  Script to detect the type of a file by its contents.  See ":help 'filetype'".

   /usr/local/lib/vim/print/*.ps
                  Files used for PostScript printing.

   For recent info read the VIM home page:
   <URL:http://www.vim.org/>
```

Answer (score -2):

On OSX Mojave, the default settings are at

`/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/`

If you want to modify any of these, it is best to copy the file you need into `~/.vim/syntax`, and modify that, thereby preserving the original.