# Unable to locate the vimrc file

Tags: vim

I am trying to update my vimrc file to add new plugins to vim. However my vimrc is not a dot file. In fact the `:scriptnames` command is displaying me this :

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

So I am not sure if I should update my `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` or should I create a new dot file at `~/.vimrc` (which does not exist on my machine yet) as it is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file)?

Comment: Yes, you should create a `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @Ryan : Thank you man. One question though please. How would vim be able to recognize the newly created ~/.vimrc file?

Comment: That’s one of the places it looks by default.

Comment: @Ryan : Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/vim/vimrc` is installed by your Linux distribution; like anything under `/usr/share`, system updates will eventually override changes you make there.

Create your own configuration in `~/.vimrc` (or `~/.vim/vimrc`); if you avoid hard-coding of paths, you can even share this across multiple systems that you use. Vim will automatically use this file on the next start. See `:help vimrc` for details.

The only use case for editing system-wide configuration is when you are the system administrator of a multi-user system (e.g. for students), and you want to make everyone use the same, consistent settings. Some distributions even allow to do that without touching those distribution-controlled files (via `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` in Debian, for example).