# Setting Vi editor configurations in Linux login profile

Tags: linux, unix, vi

I am using vi editor in Linux server. I want to set certain configurations like *set ai* and *set ts=4* in my login profile itself so that I don't have to set it each and every time I get into Vi editor. Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Where is my .vimrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is my .vimrc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: [Vim/.vimrc configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Example_configurations) a very good reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a the .vimrc/.exrc file for in this case.
[vimrc sample](https://github.com/cjkoikara/MyDotFiles/blob/master/vimrc)

Comment: Will vimrc file work for Vi editor. Thought it's only for Vim. Sorry  - I am new to vim

Comment: It depends. In some distributions vi might actually be vim-minimal which would use ~/.vimrc as config file. Otherwise it is .exrc file in your home directory

Comment: I have neither .vimrc nor .exrc files in my home directory.  I don't have .bashrc as well. If I create them on my own, how do I ensure it will be executed automatically when I login?

Comment: you can create one. I should be automatically used. you can source it in case you want to be sure