# How to modify/change the vimrc file in VsCode?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I am new to Vim and I have installed the Vim Extension in Vscode. I know that we can customize the default Vim Editor by modifying the vimrc file.

I want to change some keybindings in the VsCode Vim extension.  How to do it/Where will I find the vimrc of Vscode Vim?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Make sure you have a `/.vimrc` or `/_vimrc` file in `$HOME` directory and follow the follow the following steps :

1. Open VScode and go to settings.
2. Type `vimrc`
3. Enable `Use Keymappings from a .vimrc file`

[image: img1]

4. Modify the vimrc file according to your needs.

Comment: In my vimrc, how can I tell if I am in VSCode or not?  Something like `has('nvim')` for VSCode

Comment: @MaxCoplan That would depend on whose Neovim/Vim plugin you are using in Vscode. Only the developer of that plugin will know what variable to check. For example, for   [this](https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim) plugin , you will have to do [this](https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim#determining-if-running-in-vscode-in-your-initvim). So you should look through the docs of the plugin you are using

Comment: Also note that there are some plugins which donot have this feature at all(like Vscodevim). The reason is Vscodevim emulates a vim for you. On the other hand, [this](https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim#determining-if-running-in-vscode-in-your-initvim) one actually uses a Neovim instance at the backend giving you the power to bring most(if not all) of the features/plugins of your native neovim to vscode.

Comment: For users using `nvim` You can also put there `nvim` configuration like `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Comment: Sorry, but from Step 3, how do I actually open the file .vimrc in VSCode, so that I can edit it?

Comment: @MaxCoplan: apparently, `if exists('g:vscode')` at least with [neovim extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim)

Answer (score 14):

You may achieve the same result by inserting
`"vim.vimrc.enable": true` into your vscode setting.json.

Comment: Great answer. I used part of your answer to generate a more concise answer for a windows machine.

Comment: + `"vim.vimrc.path": "/path/to/.vimrc"` if you need something custom for vscode or keep it outside the home folder

Answer (score 4):

****Solution 1**:**
@Jdeep's https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030352/8652240

****Solution 2**:**
Edit your .vimrc file from your Operating system's folder.

> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> - **Windows** %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
> - **macOS** $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
> - **Linux** $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Or replace your personal .vimrc but make sure the filename is exactly (.vimrc) (yes, the period included as well)

If **solution 1 and solution 2** don't work, verify vimrc in settings.json is enabled like this:

1. Windows 10 user can open settings.json in

- C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

[image]

2. Open VS Code
3. Open settings.json (Control + ,)

- File > Preferences > Settings > Enter "settings"
- Note: don't click on a similar file named defaultSettings.json

3. Scroll down and click on link "Edit in settings.json"

[image]

4. verify "vim.vimrc.enable": true

[image]

5. Save and reload VS Code

Answer (score 2):

- Windows machine in Powershell

  ```
  cd ~

  # create the .vimrc file - it might already exist
  New-Item -ItemType File .\.vimrc 

  # Open VS Code to modify your vim settings
  code .\.vimrc
  ```
- In VS Code
  Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and type `Open Settings JSON`
- In `settings.json` add

  ```
  "vim.vimrc.enable": true
  ```
- Navigate back to your `.vimrc`

And modify it as you please.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use external path to vimrc
Go to settings.json in vscode change vimrc option to false :
"vim.vimrc.enable": false